# How to only get the "title" and "main content" of a page using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a clone of getpocket.com for learning. On that app, every saved link gets converted into a markdown; and it seems like the it's a filtered content with only the page title and body without headers, footers, etc.

I could get the page's title using **puppeteer api** thru different means:

- using `page.title()`
- or get the page's opengraph "og:title"

But how do i get like the summarized version containing only the main content of the page.

Note that i don't know beforehand the "css class" of the main content since i'm planning on just entering a url in a textbox and scrape that site from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what i've needed for this scenario.

I used the **Readability.js** library for making webpages readable by removing some certain html tags. Here's the [library](https://github.com/mozilla/readability).
This library is what mozilla uses behind the scenes when rendering their reader view